# CSS :not wont work as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select elements that doesn't have both `.test` and `.test1` classes.
The following won't work.

```css
ul li:not(.test.test1)
{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="test test1">one..</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected as per [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

> *"The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a **simple** selector X as an argument."*

Unfortunately yours in not a *simple* selector.

The [**CSS Spec**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#simple) definition of a simple selector is:

> ...an element matched by a particular aspect. A type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class is a simple selector.

Unfortunately, your is a *compound* selector as it has **two** classes.

@Rounin has the optimal solution here. The above is just explanation as to why your selector fails.

Comment: Thank you, i got it.

 it seems that selectors are differently executed for jquery and css , cos following works for jquery http://jsfiddle.net/pkUy2/47/ and not works for css

Answer (score 4):

Quite often, whenever you find yourself in a situation where you need to use `:not`, there will be a more elegant way to re-write your styles, deploying *positive* rather than *negative* targeting.

For instance, rather than targeting everything which *isn't* `.test.test1` and giving it `color:rgb(255,0,0)`, why not:

- Color *everything* `color:rgb(255,0,0)`; and then
- Positively target `.test.test1`, re-coloring it `color:rgb(0,0,0)`

That way you take advantage of the *cascade*, in exactly the way that it is supposed to work.

```css
li {
color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

li.test.test1 {
color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="test test1">one..</li>
    <li class="two">two</li>
    <li class="three">three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thinking positively is always the best way!

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
ul li:not(.test),ul li:not(.test1)
{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: But what if a li has only test or only test1 as class?

Comment: @Ron Deijkers, @Paulie_D : Thanks for pointing it out. My answer is wrong. `ul li:not(.test):not(.test1)` is the right answer and someone already did it and i cant find it in this post now.

Comment: @Tympaaz no it isn't - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5xd2dw7/1/) - it still won't select the element if it has one of those classes. As Paulie_D said, it's not a simple selector. So, IMO, Rounins answer is the best way to deal with this issue. Other solution would be to combine those two classes into one, and then use `:not()`.

Comment: @Vucko: Thank you for helping me figure it out.